# Not able to scroll down a slide content

Tags: jquery, scroll, touch, fullpage.js

using fullpage.js on a page with one section and many slide(s), i'm not able to slide up/down the content of any slide on touch device.
if i wrapp the slide content inside a `<div style="overflow-y:auto;height:100%;">content</div>`, on my touch screen enable laptop a scroll bar appears and i can scroll it with my mouse but not with my finger. on my iphone and ipad, no scrollbar appears and no scrolling is possible. same thing on my samsung runing androïd...

see example here : http://jsfiddle.net/sebmeric/nn11xxay/1/

does anyone has any idea ?

thank you

séb.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few links which might help you get scrolling in touchscreen device.

**[Link 1](http://chris-barr.com/2010/05/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/)
[Link 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Link 3](http://cssdeck.com/labs/8koulyu5)**

This is what you might need to add in your css

```
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

You can do more research on above for different browsers

Comment: thanks. i just added this webkit specific to the jsfiddle example but it doesn't do anything more on webkit browsers...
see : http://jsfiddle.net/sebmeric/nn11xxay/3/.

the 3rd link you gave here is a good example of a scrollable div that works with all the devices i tried. so i'm pretty sure the problem is fullpage.js specific...

and i wish there is a way to scroll this scrollable div (!) without using more javascript as it should be posible in the first place...

Comment: fullpage.js might attach some styles/classes before creating element. if there exists any fullpage.css then try providing these options in the styles that has  been referred by the div..

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using a scrollable element inside fullPage.js. The plugin only scrolls from section to section, so if you want it to know that you have an scrollable element inside a section you should let it know.

You should be using the option `normalScrollElements` of fullPage.js.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor : ['#ccc', '#456'],
    normalScrollElements: '.slide-content'
});
```

From [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **normalScrollElements:** (default null) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the jQuery selectors for those elements. (For example: normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2')

And maybe even `normalScrollElementTouchThreshold`

> **normalScrollElementTouchThreshold** : (default 5) Defines the threshold for the number of hops up the html node tree Fullpage will test to see if normalScrollElements is a match to allow scrolling functionality on divs on a touch device. (For example: normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 3)